# Apache2 ,changing port in virtualhost

Tags: apache

The question is: I have api server placed on localhost:8888 and an image-server placed on localhost:8877. I want to receive all requests to 443 port (https), and than redirect to 8888 or 8877. I want to do it by condition (if "/image/": in request) because image-server requesting by this : localhost:8877/image/101?some_params

Can I receive requests to 443 and that change port by condition in VirtualHots?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this by configuring Apache as a [reverse proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html), so it can handle and pass the requests to the image server. For example:

```
ProxyPass /image http://localhost:8877/image
ProxyPassReverse /image http://localhost:8877/image
```